# Solar System Simulation - getting the acceleration

Tags: java, simulation

I am writing some simple Solar System simulation. As I started from writing the simulation for a particle moving in Earth's gravitational field, now I am trying to change the code such that it would work for all the planets and Sun.

In my main class the code I use to calculate the acceleration and then update the position and velocity of planet is:

```
double sum=0;

    while (sum<=t)
    {   
        for (int i=0; i<Solar.length; i++){

        Sun.updateAcceleration(new PhysicsVector(4.349667090137737E10,1.415796493305069E11), 5.97219E24);
        Earth.updateAcceleration(new PhysicsVector(5.165897176059002E8, 5.617786927434339E8), 1.988544E30);

        Solar[i].updateEulerCramer(dt);
        sum=sum+dt;

    }
    }
```

It calls the updateAcceleration method from Planet.class :

```
public void updateAcceleration(PhysicsVector Position2, double Mass)

{   
    Acceleration=GravField.Acceleration(Position1, Position2, Mass); 
    return; 
}
```

which, on the other hand, call the method Acceleration from Gravfield.class:

```
public static PhysicsVector Acceleration(PhysicsVector Position1, PhysicsVector Position2, double M)
{

    PhysicsVector Distance = new PhysicsVector();
    Distance=PhysicsVector.subtract(Position1,Position2);

    r=Distance.magnitude();

    g=(-1.*G*M)/Math.pow(r,2);


    return PhysicsVector.scale(g,Distance.getUnitVector());
}
```

It works for Sun and Earth, but, obviously, it will get very messy when I add other objects. What's more, I am not sure how and in which file change the code, so that it calculates the acceleration from all of the planets and stars, not only one. I would be grateful for any hint or direction where should I go from there.

Comment: Please update your names to follow [standard java naming conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions).  This makes your code more readable for us so we can more effectively help you.

Comment: FYI, this is known as an n-body problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem). Might help you when googling.